# Can a Barracuda Spam Filter 300 reject mail based on DNS?

Tags: spam, barracuda

Can a Barracuda SF 300 reject mail based on DNS?

Specifically can it respond with a 4XX code for mail claiming to be from a domain without a valid MX or A record (similar to postfix's `smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain`).

If so, how do I set it? (I realize it's probably something simple I've overlooked.)

The barracuda can resolve using its configured name servers.
The name servers can correctly resolve external domains.

Comment: If you have a support contract, their technical support is pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Apparently barracuda previously had this option, but removed it some time ago do to a DOS vulnerability it exposed their system to. (I believe related to a domain with a large number of MX records.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, sorta. Assuming you have a recent firmware edition, navigating to `Block/Accept -> Reverse DNS`, you have the following options:

[image]

Specific error or bounce-back messages can be configured in `Advanced -> Bounce/NDR Settings`. You may also want to look at the `Deep Header Scan` option.